# Not able to read XML file

Tags: java, xml, struts

When I am trying to read xml file from my Java code, I getting error as shown in attached image.
[image]

Java code :

```
public ActionForward xmlupload(ActionMapping mapping,
            ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String target = new String("success");

    System.out.println("I AM IN ACTION");
 List<XmltodbBO> branchList = new ArrayList<XmltodbBO>();
 try {
      File file = new File("D:\\FNDWRR.xml");
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = db.parse(file);
      doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("fsg:RptLine");
      System.out.println("Root Tag value");
      XmltodbDAO sim=new XmltodbDAO();

      for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {
          XmltodbBO bO=new XmltodbBO();
        Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

        if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {



               Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;
          NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("fsg:RptCell");
          System.out.print(fstNmElmntLst.getLength());
          Node current = fstNmElmntLst.item(0);

              if(current.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){


                 String nodeName = current.getNodeName();
              Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);

              NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
              Text itemCheckedText = (Text) fstNm.item(0);
              if (itemCheckedText != null) {
              System.out.println("Tag value : "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
              bO.setFirstfieldName( fstNm.item(0).getNodeValue());

              }

              }



             if( fstNmElmntLst.getLength()>1){

               Node current1 = fstNmElmntLst.item(1);
                 if(current1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                 Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(1);
                 NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
              Text itemCheckedText1 = (Text) fstNm.item(0);
              if (itemCheckedText1 != null) {
              System.out.println("Tag value : "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
              bO.setSecondfieldName( fstNm.item(0).getNodeValue());

              }
               }


              }

             if( fstNmElmntLst.getLength()>2){

               Node current1 = fstNmElmntLst.item(2);
                 if(current1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                 Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(2);
                 NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
              Text itemCheckedText1 = (Text) fstNm.item(0);
              if (itemCheckedText1 != null) {
              System.out.println("Tag value : "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
              bO.setThirdfieldName(fstNm.item(0).getNodeValue());

              }
               }


              }
        }  branchList.add( bO); }

      sim.adddb(branchList);


              }

catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
     return (mapping.findForward(target));
 }
```

When I am running the same application using main class, it is working fine. But when I am trying to do the same using struts action, I am getting this error. Please help me out.

Comment: Which charset are you using? The error states it's finding an unusual character on the XML... could you post it?

Comment: try to open the XML using IE, it will give you the location of invalid character.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace indicates that you are using xerces as your xml parser (as opposed to the xml parser which is part of the jre/jdk).  using a different xml parser can cause all kinds of problems.  unless you are doing that intentionally, i would recommend removing it.  (if you are using a build system like maven, sometimes you will get transitive dependencies on "xercesImpl" or xml-apis" jars.  you should *exclude* these in your pom.)

Comment: I disagree strongly with this advice. The XML parser in the JDK is thoroughly buggy, the Apache Xerces one is far better.

Comment: @MichaelKay - well, the jdk impl is based on xerces, albeit an old version.  and, yes, the builtin version has its issues for sure.  but 9 times out of 10 when something goes sideways when working with xml, it's due to accidentally pulling in xercesImpl (often an old version).  there are many xml apis (jaxp, jaxws, jaxb) in java and the builtin impls at least have the benefit of playing nicely with each other.

Comment: The bugs in the JDK don't affect 10% of all runs, sure. They probably only affect one run in 5,000. That makes the bugs especially pernicious - you don't discover them until you've gone live.

Comment: @MichaelKay - my point is that including xercesImpl causes _far_ more (obvious) issues than using the jdk's built-in parser, often due to bad interactions with other xml apis in the jdk.  i personally have yet to run into a "show-stopper" issue with the jdk xml parser.

Comment: Well, my experience is exactly the opposite. I have never had any problems with the Apache Xerces parser, and I have had lots of problems with the JDK parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a reader to parse and specify a character set:

```
Document document = builder.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

I also agree with the other answer that you might be pulling in an old/different xml parser by mistake.